# not found "App-Specific Shared Secret" Location inside Subscription Section of App Store Connect

Tags: ios, app-store, app-store-connect

"App-Specific Shared Secret" does not exist inside Subscription section in App Store Connect. Previously it was below Billing Grace Period section. Any idea where it is moved?
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It has moved to "General -> App Information" inside App Store Connect